# Odoo. How to create a view to extended model

Tags: odoo

I am very new in odoo and i really need your help.

I've extended **res.partner** :

```
    class extendedPartner(models.Model):
_name = 'extended.partner'    
_inherit = 'res.partner' 

auto = fields.One2Many('partner.car', 'auto_name', 'Car', required=False)

    class partnerCar(models.Model):
_name = 'partner.car'

auto_model = fields.Char('Model auto', size=20, required=True)  
release = fields.Integer('Year of release', required=True)

auto_name = fields.Many2One('extended.partner', 'Car Name', required=True)
```

But I don't know how to write **xml** so that I could see all partner's cars and information about them

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_partner_form">
<field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
<field name="model">extended.partner</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <notebook position="inside">
        <page string="Cars">
            <!-- what should I write here? -->
        </page>
    </notebook>
</field>
</record>
```

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

**UPD:**

Is it right solution?

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_partner_form">
<field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
<field name="model">extended.partner</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="auto">
       <tree>
           <field name="auto_name"/>
           <field name="auto_model"/>
           <field name="release"/>
       </tree>
    </field>
</field>
</record>
```

Comment: I've updated my post. Could you please check if there is right solution?

Comment: @Grzegorzg Did you try your solution to see if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, since you inherit from another view and you injecting your view into the view you inherit from, you need to give your new view a "hook" in the parent view which it can use to attach its contents. So you use an `xpath` expression, and then you insert your field.

When you insert a relational field you can create so called `embedded` views. Here you have defined a `tree` view for your field. That means whenever your field will be rendered as a `tree` that is the `tree` that will be used, in your case the form.

You could also create a `<form>` after `<tree>` to be shown when clicked.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_partner_form">
    <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">extended.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="insert_x_path_xpression here" position="after, before etc"
        <field name="auto">
           <tree>
               <field name="auto_name"/>
               <field name="auto_model"/>
               <field name="release"/>
           </tree>
        </field>
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```